# Bash: selection of the strings from txt by keywords

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Within some working directory I have N log files with the contact information made in the following format:

```
For chain.A it has been detected 13 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:116.A@SC2  :295.K@SC1  -0.948  4.488
:142.A@SC1  :23.K@SC3   -0.972  4.512
:142.A@BB   :23.K@SC3   -0.973  4.403
:145.A@SC1  :66.K@SC1   -1.006  4.546
:118.A@SC1  :296.K@SC2  -1.031  4.571
:185.A@SC1  :21.K@SC1   -1.048  4.588
:128.A@SC1  :35.K@SC1   -1.062  4.602
:105.A@SC1  :28.K@SC3   -1.070  4.610
:185.A@SC1  :25.K@SC1   -1.095  4.635
:108.A@SC1  :301.K@SC1  -1.167  4.707
:175.A@SC1  :70.K@SC1   -1.178  4.718
:139.A@SC1  :24.K@SC1   -1.192  4.732
:120.A@BB   :296.K@SC3  -1.196  4.626
For chain.B it has been detected 7 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:111.B@SC3  :39.M@SC2   -0.944  4.484
:178.B@BB   :84.M@SC1   -1.077  4.507
:70.B@SC1   :181.K@SC1  -1.101  4.641
:21.B@SC1   :184.K@SC1  -1.116  4.656
:28.B@SC2   :193.K@SC1  -1.142  4.682
:115.B@BB   :39.M@SC3   -1.158  4.588
:197.B@SC1  :32.M@SC1   -1.169  4.709
For chain.C it has been detected 0 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
For chain.D it has been detected 0 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
For chain.E it has been detected 2 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:179.E@SC1  :249.J@SC1  -1.012  4.552
:179.E@SC1  :245.J@SC3  -1.017  4.557
```

Using a bash script I need to post-process each of the log files in order to create a new "reduced" log, that should contain only the strings from the initial log with the number of contacts, thus reducing the above example to

```
For chain.A it has been detected 13 contacts
For chain.B it has been detected 7 contacts
For chain.C it has been detected 0 contacts
For chain.D it has been detected 0 contacts
For chain.E it has been detected 2 contacts
```

And finally to add at the bottom of the new log detailed info regarding the TOTAL number of the contacts, in the following format:

```
TOTAL=13+7+0+0+2=22 contacts
```

UPDATE!
using the following perl script:

```
perl -ne '/For chain/ && /(\d+)/ && ($str.=$1) && ($sum+=$1) && print; END{print "Total=",join "+",(split//,$str);print "=$sum contacts\n",}' $log > ${output}/${log_tit}_Contacts.log
```

with the below example

```
 For chain.A it has been detected 0 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
For chain.B it has been detected 5 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:28.B@SC3  :235.N@SC2  -0.779  4.319
:79.B@SC1  :259.N@SC2  -1.005  4.545
:74.B@SC1  :259.N@BB   -1.021  4.451
:78.B@SC4  :260.N@SC1  -1.112  4.652
:28.B@SC1  :235.N@SC2  -1.199  4.739
For chain.C it has been detected 18 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:235.C@SC3  :101.I@SC1  -0.604  4.144
:235.C@SC1  :190.I@SC1  -0.828  4.368
:203.C@SC1  :111.I@SC3  -0.859  4.399
:266.C@SC1  :175.I@SC1  -0.879  4.419
:175.C@SC1  :70.J@SC1   -0.921  4.461
:192.C@SC1  :190.I@SC3  -1.024  4.564
:142.C@SC1  :63.J@SC1   -1.029  4.569
:207.C@SC1  :116.I@SC3  -1.050  4.590
:192.C@SC1  :190.I@SC2  -1.073  4.613
:235.C@SC3  :101.I@SC3  -1.079  4.619
:131.C@SC1  :35.J@SC1   -1.094  4.634
:227.C@SC1  :111.I@SC2  -1.099  4.639
:207.C@SC2  :117.I@SC1  -1.101  4.641
:192.C@SC3  :193.I@SC1  -1.125  4.665
:203.C@SC3  :111.I@SC3  -1.142  4.682
:231.C@SC1  :194.I@SC1  -1.158  4.698
:267.C@BB   :178.I@BB   -1.159  4.479
:203.C@BB   :201.I@SC1  -1.162  4.592
For chain.D it has been detected 12 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:116.D@SC2  :203.P@SC3  -0.674  4.214
:80.D@SC3   :83.M@SC3   -0.789  4.329
:190.D@SC2  :188.P@SC1  -0.865  4.405
:28.D@SC3   :101.M@SC1  -1.000  4.540
:181.D@SC1  :245.P@SC3  -1.038  4.578
:201.D@SC1  :197.P@SC1  -1.062  4.602
:74.D@SC1   :149.M@SC1  -1.089  4.629
:296.D@SC2  :116.M@SC3  -1.115  4.255
:193.D@SC1  :193.P@SC1  -1.124  4.664
:63.D@SC1   :135.M@SC1  -1.149  4.689
:39.D@SC3   :121.M@SC1  -1.151  4.691
:23.D@SC3   :143.M@BB   -1.186  4.616
For chain.E it has been detected 3 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:10.E@SC3   :80.I@SC3   -0.885  4.425
:10.E@SC2   :78.I@SC4   -0.908  4.448
:301.E@SC1  :288.I@SC3  -1.125  4.665
For chain.F it has been detected 22 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:80.F@SC3   :245.L@SC1  -0.801  4.341
:179.F@SC1  :183.K@BB   -0.924  4.354
:38.F@SC3   :111.L@SC2  -0.940  4.480
:78.F@SC1   :254.L@SC1  -0.942  4.482
:190.F@SC3  :105.K@SC1  -0.944  4.484
:59.F@SC1   :190.L@SC2  -0.976  4.516
:35.F@SC1   :111.L@SC3  -1.001  4.541
:197.F@SC1  :127.K@SC1  -1.034  4.574
:28.F@SC2   :196.L@SC1  -1.047  4.587
:193.F@SC1  :131.K@SC1  -1.052  4.592
:190.F@SC3  :101.K@SC1  -1.060  4.600
:117.F@SC1  :119.K@SC2  -1.138  4.678
:190.F@BB   :135.K@SC1  -1.138  4.568
:78.F@SC2   :254.L@SC1  -1.141  4.681
:80.F@SC3   :245.L@SC3  -1.151  4.691
:63.F@SC1   :186.L@SC1  -1.158  4.698
:190.F@SC1  :135.K@SC1  -1.162  4.702
:101.F@SC3  :190.K@SC3  -1.164  4.704
:300.F@SC1  :201.L@SC1  -1.169  4.709
:116.F@SC1  :119.K@BB   -1.176  4.606
:80.F@SC3   :249.L@SC1  -1.186  4.726
:84.F@SC1   :181.L@SC1  -1.200  4.740
For chain.G it has been detected 7 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:259.G@SC1  :78.P@SC3   -0.943  4.483
:236.G@BB   :24.P@SC1   -0.999  4.429
:10.G@SC1   :10.P@SC3   -1.002  4.542
:14.G@SC1   :14.P@SC1   -1.011  4.551
:238.G@BB   :24.P@SC1   -1.101  4.531
:259.G@SC2  :157.P@SC1  -1.136  4.676
:260.G@SC1  :74.P@SC1   -1.147  4.687
For chain.H it has been detected 0 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
For chain.I it has been detected 18 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:101.I@SC1  :235.C@SC3  -0.604  4.144
:190.I@SC1  :235.C@SC1  -0.828  4.368
:111.I@SC3  :203.C@SC1  -0.859  4.399
:175.I@SC1  :266.C@SC1  -0.879  4.419
:80.I@SC3   :10.E@SC3   -0.885  4.425
:78.I@SC4   :10.E@SC2   -0.908  4.448
:190.I@SC3  :192.C@SC1  -1.024  4.564
:116.I@SC3  :207.C@SC1  -1.050  4.590
:190.I@SC2  :192.C@SC1  -1.073  4.613
:101.I@SC3  :235.C@SC3  -1.079  4.619
:111.I@SC2  :227.C@SC1  -1.099  4.639
:117.I@SC1  :207.C@SC2  -1.101  4.641
:193.I@SC1  :192.C@SC3  -1.125  4.665
:288.I@SC3  :301.E@SC1  -1.125  4.665
:111.I@SC3  :203.C@SC3  -1.142  4.682
:194.I@SC1  :231.C@SC1  -1.158  4.698
:178.I@BB   :267.C@BB   -1.159  4.479
:201.I@SC1  :203.C@BB   -1.162  4.592
For chain.J it has been detected 3 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:70.J@SC1  :175.C@SC1  -0.921  4.461
:63.J@SC1  :142.C@SC1  -1.029  4.569
:35.J@SC1  :131.C@SC1  -1.094  4.634
For chain.K it has been detected 10 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:183.K@BB   :179.F@SC1  -0.924  4.354
:105.K@SC1  :190.F@SC3  -0.944  4.484
:127.K@SC1  :197.F@SC1  -1.034  4.574
:131.K@SC1  :193.F@SC1  -1.052  4.592
:101.K@SC1  :190.F@SC3  -1.060  4.600
:119.K@SC2  :117.F@SC1  -1.138  4.678
:135.K@SC1  :190.F@BB   -1.138  4.568
:135.K@SC1  :190.F@SC1  -1.162  4.702
:190.K@SC3  :101.F@SC3  -1.164  4.704
:119.K@BB   :116.F@SC1  -1.176  4.606
For chain.L it has been detected 12 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:245.L@SC1  :80.F@SC3   -0.801  4.341
:111.L@SC2  :38.F@SC3   -0.940  4.480
:254.L@SC1  :78.F@SC1   -0.942  4.482
:190.L@SC2  :59.F@SC1   -0.976  4.516
:111.L@SC3  :35.F@SC1   -1.001  4.541
:196.L@SC1  :28.F@SC2   -1.047  4.587
:254.L@SC1  :78.F@SC2   -1.141  4.681
:245.L@SC3  :80.F@SC3   -1.151  4.691
:186.L@SC1  :63.F@SC1   -1.158  4.698
:201.L@SC1  :300.F@SC1  -1.169  4.709
:249.L@SC1  :80.F@SC3   -1.186  4.726
:181.L@SC1  :84.F@SC1   -1.200  4.740
For chain.M it has been detected 7 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:83.M@SC3   :80.D@SC3   -0.789  4.329
:101.M@SC1  :28.D@SC3   -1.000  4.540
:149.M@SC1  :74.D@SC1   -1.089  4.629
:116.M@SC3  :296.D@SC2  -1.115  4.255
:135.M@SC1  :63.D@SC1   -1.149  4.689
:121.M@SC1  :39.D@SC3   -1.151  4.691
:143.M@BB   :23.D@SC3   -1.186  4.616
For chain.N it has been detected 5 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:235.N@SC2  :28.B@SC3  -0.779  4.319
:259.N@SC2  :79.B@SC1  -1.005  4.545
:259.N@BB   :74.B@SC1  -1.021  4.451
:260.N@SC1  :78.B@SC4  -1.112  4.652
:235.N@SC2  :28.B@SC1  -1.199  4.739
For chain.O it has been detected 0 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
For chain.P it has been detected 12 contacts
atom1  atom2  overlap  distance
:203.P@SC3  :116.D@SC2  -0.674  4.214
:188.P@SC1  :190.D@SC2  -0.865  4.405
:78.P@SC3   :259.G@SC1  -0.943  4.483
:24.P@SC1   :236.G@BB   -0.999  4.429
:10.P@SC3   :10.G@SC1   -1.002  4.542
:14.P@SC1   :14.G@SC1   -1.011  4.551
:245.P@SC3  :181.D@SC1  -1.038  4.578
:197.P@SC1  :201.D@SC1  -1.062  4.602
:24.P@SC1   :238.G@BB   -1.101  4.531
:193.P@SC1  :193.D@SC1  -1.124  4.664
:157.P@SC1  :259.G@SC2  -1.136  4.676
:74.P@SC1   :260.G@SC1  -1.147  4.687
```

I have a good output but the info regarding chain.A (where was 0 contacts in the initial file) is missed. Moreover the total sum at the end of the output was calculated in a wrong manner splitting 15 to 1+5 etc

```
For chain.B it has been detected 5 contacts
For chain.C it has been detected 18 contacts
For chain.D it has been detected 12 contacts
For chain.E it has been detected 3 contacts
For chain.F it has been detected 22 contacts
For chain.G it has been detected 7 contacts
For chain.H it has been detected 0 contacts
For chain.I it has been detected 18 contacts
For chain.J it has been detected 3 contacts
For chain.K it has been detected 10 contacts
For chain.L it has been detected 12 contacts
For chain.M it has been detected 7 contacts
For chain.N it has been detected 5 contacts
For chain.O it has been detected 0 contacts
For chain.P it has been detected 12 contacts
Total=0+5+1+8+1+2+3+2+2+7+0+1+8+3+1+0+1+2+7+5+0+1+2=134 contacts
```

Comment: and what have you tried to solve this? ... how'd the solution you get be `simple bash script` if you don't show what is your level of understanding?

Comment: I could not understand the pattern of this output: `TOTAL=18+18+2+0+22+7+32+11+6+5` which you commented me.  Please **clarify** your desire output.

Answer (score 1):

Following simple `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/For chain.*detected.*contacts/{count+=$(NF-1)} END{print count}'  Input_file
```

Output will be `22`.

In case you want to have Input_file name in output too then following may help you on same.

```
awk '/For chain.*detected.*contacts/{count+=$(NF-1)} END{print count > FILENAME".log"}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to put this AWK trick into the for loop (when I looping all of the logs) in order to add the calculated number of the contacts from each log in a new string of the Total_contact.txt that should be updated during each loop step. The following aws statement didn't work for me :  awk '/For chain.*detected.*contacts/{count+=$(NF-1)} END{print count}' $log >> ${output}/Total_Contacts.log

Comment: @user3470313, could you please do let me know what is not working here? Or you are getting any errors.

Comment: actually I was interested if it would possible to add within this AWK expression something to indicate from which original file the summ was calculated. that I do via printf before the AWK like printf "The total number of contacts under the pressure of ${log_tit}: " >> ${output}/Total_Contacts.log
awk '/For chain.*detected.*contacts/{count+=$(NF-1)} END{print count}' $log >> ${output}/Total_Contacts.log

Comment: So you want output to be like eg--> Input_file".log"?

Comment: @user3470313, check my added solution too now if that helps you it will save output into a output file whose name is Input_file's name with a added ".out" in it too.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne '/For chain/g && /(\d+)/ && print && ($str.=$1.",") && ($sum+=$1); END{print "TOTAL=",join "+",(split/,/,$str);print "=$sum contacts\n",}' file
```

if you do not mind using **Perl**

```
For chain.A it has been detected 13 contacts
For chain.B it has been detected 7 contacts
For chain.C it has been detected 0 contacts
For chain.D it has been detected 0 contacts
For chain.E it has been detected 2 contacts
Total=13+7+0+0+2=22 contacts
```

and for your second log:

```
 For chain.A it has been detected 0 contacts
For chain.B it has been detected 5 contacts
For chain.C it has been detected 18 contacts
For chain.D it has been detected 12 contacts
For chain.E it has been detected 3 contacts
For chain.F it has been detected 22 contacts
For chain.G it has been detected 7 contacts
For chain.H it has been detected 0 contacts
For chain.I it has been detected 18 contacts
For chain.J it has been detected 3 contacts
For chain.K it has been detected 10 contacts
For chain.L it has been detected 12 contacts
For chain.M it has been detected 7 contacts
For chain.N it has been detected 5 contacts
For chain.O it has been detected 0 contacts
For chain.P it has been detected 12 contacts
TOTAL=0+5+18+12+3+22+7+0+18+3+10+12+7+5+0+12=134 contacts
```

Comment: that a good but there are two bugs. 1) it did not include the string for the Chain A (the first string) if it contains 0 contacts. E.g if the initial log has "For chain.A it has been detected 0 contacts" it will not be added to the output file. 2) in the bottom of the TOTAL it displays the sum contribution not correctly. E.g for For chain.A it has been detected 14 contacts
For chain.B it has been detected 20 contacts; Total=1+4+2+0

Comment: @user3470313. **for 1**: clarify your question or explain each condition you need. **for 2**. add more log files or examples output and your attempt to solve

Comment: there is a bug with the first string and also in the calculation of the total sum at the end I modify the first post of the topic for the demonstration!

Comment: @user3470313. I saw the problem. Let me check

Comment: @user3470313 The total for the first log is `22` and for the second one is `134` if they are incorrect, so what is the **correct number**?

Comment: That works now!! Thank you so much!!  the problem was only in the calculation of the CONTRIBUTION of each string in the final sum as I indicated at the first topic. like  # that is correct TOTAL=18+18+2+0+22+7+32+11+6+5 ...